# Cant connect dockerized springboot application to not dockerized postgres database (localhost)

Tags: java, spring, docker

Im getting the connection refused error, but in my eclipse it connects with no problem. I wonder if it is not possible to connect to a database that hasnt been dockerized also or if its possible what should I do?

thise is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/permisos.jar permisos.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/permisos.jar"]
```

this is my application.yml file:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/permisosdb
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address of the host is `host.docker.internal` on, AFAIK, all modern Docker installations.

So your datasource URL should be

```
url: jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/permisosdb
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
url: jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.1:5432/permisosdb
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much it worked with the first method, it would be cool if you could add the source of this information, so I can study more about this kind of configurations

Comment: I tried seeing if I could find something in the official docs. The best I found is this where it's listed as a workaround: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds. On re-reading it I can see that it seems that how you reach the host is still dependent on your host OS. The `host.docker.internal` is for Windows. `172.17.0.1` is for Linux. I don't know about Mac.

Comment: Perfect, good to take notes about it for the future, cheers